# Haskell List to Tuple

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, tuples

I am writing a function, `parseArgs`, which will take in command line arguments in the form of a list. If the size of the list is two, the function is to parse the contents of the list and convert them to a tuple, otherwise returning `Nothing`. I am unsure of quite how to go about this; my code thus far is below:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Maybe (String, Maybe String)
parseArgs [x, y]
  | length [x, y] < 2 = Nothing
  | length [x, y] > 2 = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (x, Just y)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code,
`parseArgs [x, y]` means it only accepts exactly a list of two elements.
So `length [x, y]` will always be 2, and those (>2) (<2) conditions will never be met.

`otherwise` will always be a list of two elements. So when the input is a list of two elements, you can get x and y, and make them a Maybe tuple for sure.

But other than that, if you `parseArgs []` `parseArgs ["a"]` `parseArgs ["a","b","c"]`, you get an exception "Non-exhaustive patterns in function parseArgs".
It is because the code didn't cover all the patterns in `[String]`

I use Maybe (String, String) for output here. It means parseArg will either produce Just (String, String) or Nothing. Perhaps it's closer to what you want.

So try this:

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Maybe (String, String)
parseArgs x:y:[] = Just (x,y)
parseArgs xs = Nothing
```

It means if the input [String] happens to be x:y:[] (a list of exact two strings), produce Just (x,y). Other than that, produce Nothing. In this way, it covers all patterns in [String]. And you then can get `Nothing` when it is not a list of two elements.

Edit:
And second to @pdoherty926's `parseArgs _ = Nothing`, the wildcard _ is a better way to express "everything else".

Answer (score 5):

@Johhny Liao beat me to it, but here's my similar answer:

Based on your requirements, I'm unclear as to why the second tuple element would be `Maybe String`. So, I'm going to proceed as though the type of your function is: `parseArgs :: [String] -> Maybe (String, String)`

```
parseArgs :: [String] -> Maybe (String, String)
parseArgs [x, xx] = Just (x, xx)  -- pattern match on the list of two elements
parseArgs _ = Nothing               -- discard _everything_ else

print $ parseArgs ["hi", "bye"]    -- Just ("hi", "bye")
print $ parseArgs ["hi"]               -- Nothing
```